# Copy or Sed operation inside subprocess /os.system() is not working properly

Tags: python, sed, subprocess

I want to copy 1 file to other and use other file. My actual job is to use sed but facing same issue with copy.

```
cmd='cp /home/insetl/saurabh/voluum_data.csv /home/insetl/saurabh/voluum_datax.csv'
os.system(cmd)
```

After executing, the size of files are different.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 insetl insetl 5103616 Mar 26 08:08 voluum_datax.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 insetl insetl 5106888 Mar 26 08:08 voluum_data.csv
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So... I don't get it. If your problem is with sed, why are you showing us cp?

Comment: Coz for both of them,the problem is the file is not getting processed completely. Last few lines of the files are not getting processed by both copy and sed.

Comment: No space left on filesystem?

Comment: What is missing? `diff voluum_data.csv voluum_datax.csv`

Comment: What about the result code of the operation/output? Have you tried `subprocess.check_output`?

Comment: Just be make sure: does it work on the command line?